# Java Arrays Manipulation

Tags: java, arrays

I am working on a Java Code using  Netbeans, I have to store the inputs(Student's Marks) inserted  in a `textField1` into Array, when I want to access the array in an other class(to calculate the average and set it to  `textfield2`).

I get this error `"Cannot find Symbole variable:name_of_Array"`, is there any package I am supposed to import or am I doing something wrong? I will appreciate your help!

Comment: Put your working code in your question. It will help greatly in determining what you are doing wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hard to say what you are doing wrong without looking at your code. But here is the general way of doing it. Lets say you have two classes like this:

```
class OtherClass{

    private int accessMe = 10;
    public int accessMe2 = 20;
    public static int accessMe4 = 50;

    public OtherClass(){

        int accessMe3 = 40;

    }

}
```

To access the variables of OtherClass:

```
class Access{

    public static void main(String args[]){

        OtherClass other = new OtherClass();            

        //this is not valid - because accessMe is declared as private in OtherClass
        //meaning you can only use/access accessMe variable inside the scope of OtherClass
        //If you had to access this variable, you would put a getter/setter in your OtherClass implementation.
        int accessMe = other.accessMe;

        //this is valid - because there is no particular restriction on accessMe2 inside OtherClass
        int accessMe2 = other.accessMe2;

        //this is not valid since accessMe3 is declared inside the local scope (which is the contructor of OtherClass)
        //You do not have access to accessMe3 except inside the constructor
        int accessMe3 = other.accessMe3;

        //this is valid since accessMe4 is a static variable
        int accessMe4 = OtherClass.accessMe4;

    }


}
```

As you can see, it highly depends on how you declared your array. Did you declare it private? public? static? protected? Where is it declared? Does the class belong to a completely different project? (In which case, you have to import)

Also you can change the variable type to whatever you need in the example.

Comment: Thank you a lot for your help I declared the Arrays as a local variable, now I have changed it to global .